# Magento 2 : How Can I Add Arabic URL to Products and Collections

Tags: magento2, product, url, arabic

How can I add Arabic URL to products and collections in my Magento 2 store?

Comment: Can you provide your current code and the error that occurs?

Comment: Did you got any solution.? if yes.. Please share here..  I too need arbic in product url..

Comment: I had found the solution :) go and install  this extension on github repository  https://github.com/studioraz/magento2-unicode-url

Answer (score 1):

I had found the Solution, Go and install this custom Module on this [Link](https://github.com/studioraz/magento2-unicode-url)
After that you can use the unicode URL for the Products / categories and cms Pages

Comment: It is worked great